# Comparing values of lists

Tags: c#

Another list comparing question. I now want to compare a quantity of an item to another quantity, and if the quantity of the first item is greater than or equal to the second item, return true.

```
public bool Equals(Item item1, Item item2)
{
    if (item1.ItemName.Equals(item2.ItemName) && item1.ItemCount >= item2.ItemCount)
    {
        return true;
    }
```

But no matter what the quantity of the first item, it always returns true. Is there a problem with this block of code or it the problem elsewhere?

```
var commonItems = Items.Intersect(Inventory.Items, new ListComparer()).ToList();

if (commonItems.Count() == Items.Count())
{
    return Output;
}
```

This is where I'm comparing the lists. Items would have 3 objects of class Item. 1 rock, 1 twig, and 2 vines. This is being compared against my inventory, and even if I only have 1 vine it returns true.

Forgot to add that the first block of code is in a class called

```
public class ListComparer :IEqualityComparer<Item>
```

Comment: I don't see any lists in your code.

Comment: The problem has to be with the ItemCount member of Item class (providing your items match the EXACT name - case sensitive)

Comment: Er, you are breaking the semantics of `Equals` (see [guidelines](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bsc2ak47.aspx) - half-way down the page). Weird stuff is going to happen. If a Equals b, then b should Equals a. What are you trying to achieve with this?

Comment: A crafting system like minecraft or terraria

Comment: OK, slightly less broadly, what are you trying to get out of the code that returns Output? Are you checking if two lists contain the same items..?

Comment: Yes. And if the list Inventory contains the list Items(which is basicaly a recipe for an item thats going to be crafted), then the output will be the result of the recipe that is being crafted.

Comment: I think I see. Added an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So you have a "recipe" like `[1 rock, 1 twig, 3 vine]`, and you want to know if your inventory has all items with at least the required quantities.

Here's one way you could use:

```
if (Recipe.All(r => Inventory.Any(i => 
    i.Name == r.Name && i.ItemCount >= r.ItemCount))))
```

So, "if every recipe item matches an inventory item with at least the required quantity". This is assuming there won't be multiple stacks of anything in either list.

What you shouldn't do is redefine `Equals` to mean anything except "equals". A lot of framework code works under the assumption that Equals will work consistently - for example, the result of a.Equals(b) will be the same as b.Equals(a). This is probably what is tripping you up currently, because your code does not provide this, and the `Intersect` method will be relying upon it.

Comment: This makes more sense to me. Where do the r and i variables come from?

Comment: Ah, that's lambda syntax. They're like `foreach` variables, basically - `r` will be set to each item in `Recipe` in turn, for example.

Comment: Oh I had a brain fart... but this still isn't working correctly. I can have 1 vine and the output will still be returned.

Comment: Found the bug. Was setting the variable of ItemCount in the list wrong. But this works now :)